# Rails lib includes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include

I have a puzzling issue regarding modules defined in the lib dir

I have two files

```
#lib/authentication.rb

module Authentication

end


#lib/test_module.rb

module TestModule

end
```

In my application controller I have

```
 class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
     include Authentication
     include TestModule
 end
```

The Authentication Module loads properly but the TestModule does not

I get "uninitialized constant ApplicationController::TestModule"

I am stumped... anyone?

EDIT: Does anyone know where I could look to debug this?

Comment: Silly question, but did you restart your server?  If not does restarting the process fix it?

Comment: yup I did try restarting. The server fails to start up after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding `require 'lib/test_module'` at the top of your ApplicationController file might help

Comment: Tried that one and this is what I got

no such file to load -- lib/test_module (MissingSourceFile)

Comment: Are you sure that the file is in the right place?? Since the require statement is unable to find it...

Comment: I was sure that it was in the right place but I double checked again. For some reason the file name was test_module.r?b. This is odd since it displays in TextMate(where I created the file) as .rb. I renamed the file and it worked. Thank you for your time on this, I was so puzzled I needed another set of eyes on it.

Answer (score 21):

As of Rails 3, make sure to add the `lib` directory to `config.autoload_paths` in `config/application.rb`, so that the file containing your module is read and the module is loaded.

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3) for more info on this and loading subdirectories.

Also, [supposedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356742/best-way-to-load-module-class-from-lib-folder-in-rails-3#comment3541227_3376401) "**you shouldn't use require** within a rails app, because it prevents ActiveSupport::Dependencies from [un]loading that code properly".