# How do you include a module/mixin in a presenter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a presenter in `models/presenters/my_presenter.rb`.

I have a mixin in `lib/presenter_helper.rb`.

I am trying to include the mixin inside my presenter. How do I include the mixin?

This is what I have right now, but it doesn't work:

```
class MyPresenter
  include PresenterHelper


end
```

I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant MyPresenter::PresenterHelper (NameError)
```

Comment: Here is your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11089418/1290852

Comment: Ty, and yes this is a duplicate.